# Why is it called a semi-truck? Doesn’t “semi” mean “part”?

Tags: etymology, nouns, american-english

I was wondering why semi-trucks are called that. Doesn’t *semi* mean “part of”? A semi-truck is a whole truck if I ever saw one!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Semi truck* or *semi* is short for *semi-trailer truck*.[¹](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/semitruck) The prefix *semi-* literally means *half*.[²](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=semi-) The term  describes a truck consisting of a tractor and a semi-trailer. A semi-trailer is semi-supported (half supported) by its own wheels, which support only the rear of the trailer. The front of the trailer is supported by the rear wheels of the tractor.[³](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer)

[image: picture of a semi-trailer truck]

Comment: Yes, see [*this link*](http://www.infrastructure.gov.au/roads/vehicle_regulation/bulletin/vsb1/vsb_01_b.aspx) for more explanation.

Comment: AKA "tractor trailer"

Comment: In Australia we call the pictured contraption (including the truck body) a "semi-trailer", and the truck/tractor bit when referred to separately a "prime mover".

Comment: And in the UK this is called an "articulated lorry", or sometimes just an "artic".

Comment: @Martin: or Juggernaut!