# What is the name of the truck shown in this picture?

Tags: single-word-requests

I noticed that [questions on trucks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76769/why-is-it-called-a-semi-truck-doesnt-semi-mean-part) are generally welcome on EL&U.

The truck in the picture below is called "bisarca", a single Italian word. Translating "bisarca" with Italian-English dictionaries, I found "transporter" (a large vehicle used to carry heavy objects) and "car transporter" (a large vehicle used to carry cars). The former seems very general to me, and the latter is formed by two words. I'm therefore wondering if a *single* English word exists to name this kind of trucks:

[image]

Comment: Note that many, many single words in other languages are two (or more) words in English. So you can't always count on there being a single word translation for everything. There's usually a wellrecognised phrase you can use though.

Comment: Well, I wasn't expecting to come to this site to learn a new world in my native language :) Thanks, I did not know they were called *bisarche*!

Comment: If Wikipedia is to be believed, it's a [Semi-trailer truck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer_truck) with a "car hauler" or "auto transport" [semi-trailer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer).

Comment: If this single word is found, you will never use it enough times to offset the number of words you wasted on writing this question. And, most people won't understand what you're talking about because that word will almost certainly be some trucker jargon.

Comment: That is probably not the best source for actual knowledge, but I think this joke in [this episode of the Simpsons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mook,_the_Chef,_the_Wife_and_Her_Homer) is worth being mentioned: Homer comes home with a brand new truck. Marge: Homer, where did you get that truck ? Homer: Huh huh.. it fell off a truck.. You know... a truck truck Then Bart appears driving a "truck truck" Lisa: Where did you get that ? Bart: huh.. it fell off a truck truck ... truck

Comment: @Kaz: our goal in life is not necessarily to minimize the total number of words we use. A thousand words spent here to come up with a less wordy phrase to use in "real life" can be well worth it.

Answer (score 18):

I think Andrew Leach's answer may be UK-specific.  I am in the US and have never heard them called transporters.  Regionally, at least, we call them **car carriers**.   Yes, that's two words, but there is no single-word equivalent.   A Google image search for "car carrier" turns up a bunch of pictures similar to the search for "transporter lorry".

Comment: I've called them _car carriers_ ever since I was a kid and played with one of [these](http://p2.la-img.com/709/19366/6575378_1_l.jpg).

Answer (score 14):

The single word is, in fact, ***transporter***.

If you search Google Images for *transporter lorry* (adding *lorry* gets rid of VW Transporter vans) then by far the majority look like this from http://www.freefoto.com/preview/21-26-35/Car-Transporter. Note that the word *car* doesn't appear in the search, but does appear in most of the results.

[image: Transporter]

Comment: I'm British, and I agree *we* call these things *[car] transporters*. But if you check the UK/US corpuses in NGrams for [car transporter](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=car+transporter&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) you'll see UK prevalence is 0.0000008%, where the corresponding US value is 5-6 times lower at 0.00000015%, so I guess we're looking at a UK/US difference here.

Comment: Isn't **every** truck a *transporter*?

Comment: @Kris, in the UK, if one "drives a transporter" then the picture shows what that is. Any other sort of transporter needs qualification. And other types of lorry have different names, too.

Comment: @Kris: Not broken-down ones.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: those would be broken-down transporters. :-)

Comment: @LarsH- I think they had one of those on Star Trek

Comment: FWIW, in the UK I've never heard of anything called a transporter other than a car transporter. Pretty much everything else is commonly referred to as a <something> lorry/van/vehicle.

Answer (score 10):

The picture you show is a *car transporter* (at least in the UK...), and there is no single word for it.

It is often shortened to *transporter* as Andrew Leach mentions, but that also applies to other transporters, such as tank transporters, container transporters, cattle transporters, caravan transporters, and so on, so it is too generic to apply only to lorries that carry cars.

Answer (score 5):

Back in the 70's when CB radio was "in" and CW McCall had his hit *Convoy*,
the Trucker Slang for the car carrier was

[***A Parkin' Lot***](http://www.i10trucking.com/Truckercblingo.html)

And along those same lines:

Bull Rack = Livestock carrier
Sand Box = Dump truck
Salt Shaker = Snow plow
Garbage Hauler = Refrigerated truck for carrying perishables
Cheese Wagon = Schoolbus

Answer (score 4):

Here's what [Google Images search says for your image](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivEbxaFTgEfeJ5M8UwaN1z0HJzESVgB99aI1N4vKMp1RPfT86H6YzI-qcrqsb0khgOeZZry4I2VPZEdw_166L1NX8Rvx3g8rpZ_1x_1Fd3PUcNqlcvQyJWX4YzfmGrzrQBNV_1CAh7svqCF6Vz8qCxMwUAeAKCXFEoP6frhty85Ag50FZXdlXTjt-bRqHeAd5yScWZqJW3kPYtFxaEIKT4Rw5S7MHi56uJUO4iBN0Xt9OcCUfncNRz_1Y16RDmp2suAhPTbMlcRK1zyegZT4UremUqyuAKdSLE14HVYXDM8VXQerOvphdHcb8LM1CV6_14j2zDG3UR1HoJBCERlKDTEg7LYIy7u8FjyCfutWCMEeEySBUm_1jcfRmXRKk3QE7zf9cXrfBApCwHtEY6sMRw-rZRt5ABMOHFFmrXhx7gbHPaMePISVY00xY1ndmSeu67UrBntGcfqOFZ89UFCexOW6h1VSimkabRrrqKvR8HXuwN6rTwqlrUXgE27NaVxUu4TQCleOccO0NTulM5ki1JWKOW1qrQgdh2T7BQD-dsFvxBG76_1XbmWb6M3iqayHWSshlB4dTGeqc1WC_1HeS28JiyVHZOg8A0dqbF7CRgU8_1syeDx0XKO9iF3zdqFlmfUgpU-7tBoyNnyjEEC5Yh4hmAguoe51esBG_1kk7szhA13osMHOlAsTSDcanVqMvEcYj5_1fCIWZTuqSQLf7X1WJZEPJIxxHWZFsCndqKFf43mQYJkCXtwnL-SIDSdGPQBpgqPmLRAjCL2F3SdTjNmS5mqwoWmS0cWOJ_110WrNx3dXr2h3RaF1tpOdyq2gmlKNlrQOf8kZ6rLJNwfHplx2tM3EuQHrsrshF-iunxhoNDmtezFOnuCOIaxrjFGxqmsYPUT2hQmxo2I85Z9KPphbH_1grMv9Z7s8r_1KAR1uxoL4-M-Mvq9vPyFg_1IfbJ3vyd8xQ0WeneS4_13tZ43Invbtc_1WmK8Vs1HK7pdGqA9HybqjUIhhsU7Cl8Hya8-HjB7Vrlws1lVY00dln-N9HV2nVs1yx3fYpHAAX2uTXdOI4zaYSxzbWOG_1IH6O7aX5QMQmvYJrzdJ8jxby9j2lCFDIBthQZBWkHMVpOsv1IgGJ_1OvSPaJeAMPH8tMeDZh136cHFwVV1kMg4AGo6lcfkZZuVdfNf-M0BfOv7qz9s3c2Zgx64Ij7mwQ2XoI6RvZHi3Ejza0vA4IeIbB8D6KvMx6ORJoxF8z1D49HMaGBigY2S9bn5EDS6t8a-oViCwekOVrpjwnlACtGW6feZmKd30lpTiizIs49DV-0-ruOJ2A&num=100&hl=en&safe=active&bih=963&biw=1280). (However, I'm located in Montreal; it may skew the results.)

> Best guess for this image: **auto carriers**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is apparent from the results that the phrase refers to the transport *service*, not the vehicle. e.g. 'FS Auto Carriers is bringing service back to the **car carrier industry**' ...

Comment: That is a bogus search. You put "Auto Carrier" in the description. If you call it a "big truck with cars on it" the result is "Auto Transporter".

Comment: @MattЭллен Google puts "Auto carrier" there, sorry. I know it looks dubious. Try it yourself with the URL of the image from the OP.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator - I apologise.

Answer (score 3):

I found several references to this kind of vehicle as ***car truck***, while *car transporter* refers to a company that operates these vehicles.

As others have already stated, it's also called *car transporter* in some countries.